# Retrieving item from Droplink Rendering Parameter

Tags: fieldtype, renderfield

How can I get the referenced item from a `droplink` field in rendering parameters.

What I tried:

```
var model = new DFFVideoModel();
LookupField VideoItem = (LookupField)RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["Video Item"];
model.VideoItem = VideoItem;
return View(model);
```

IntelliSense complains that it can't convert type string to `Lookupfield`. Any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Parameters` property on the `Rendering` is just a key value pair and the value is the string containing the raw value for the field type.

```
public string this[string parameterName]
{
  get
  {
    return this.Values.ValueOrDefault<string, string>(parameterName);
  }
  set
  {
    Assert.IsNotNull((object) parameterName, nameof (parameterName));
    this.Values[parameterName] = value;
  }
}
```

So you would have to take the raw value and parse that to get the Item Id that was set in the field.

For a lookup field, this is just the ID if the item:

```
var model = new MTFVideoModel();
var videoItemRaw = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["Video Item"];
var videoItem = Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(videoItemRaw));
model.VideoItem = VideoItem;
return View(model);
```